# For a PUT call that updates a resource, what is the expexcted behaviour if the enity name in the URL does not match one in the request body

Tags: rest, put

```
PUT user/john
{
   name: Tim
   age: 22
}
```

Here the username **john** in the URL does not match **Tim** in the request body.

- Should I ensure that these names do not mis-match?
- Should i **not** ask for the user name in the request body?

What is the general practice around this? Is this a common problem?